# Different Facebook Payment Issue

Tags: facebook

I new here at stackexchange and I would like to ask a question about Facebook Payment Issue. I am trying to Buy Gold in a game on facebook (GodsWar Online) and trying to pay using mobile payment but notice a big difference in my payment. The game gold for 2,000 gold cost P450.00 in my friends facebook account and in my account it's P500.00. I tried to contact the game and the facebook support and boku. But they all say that they don't know the issue they keep saying please contact boku, please contact facebook. If anyone know how to solve this issue please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, but a user support issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is not normally the type of post on stackoverflow. However, if i was going to guess it the pricing is set by IGG Inc.(http://livechat.igg.com/livesupport2/livesupport.php?gid=7) in Singapore and you are contacting the wrong people completely.